# At command check incoming call is forwarded or normal call

Tags: command, at-command

**At commands to check incoming call is forwarded call or normal call**
i have usb 3g modem with voice call support.
i want to detect incoming call is forwarded call or normal call.
like android phone can detect and shown forwarded call. that's it.
please help.. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

You need to be familiar with 3GPP TS 27.007

Refer http://www.3gpp.org

From V14.3.0 (2017-03) [Sec 7-11]:

> ```
>  Defined values
>  <reason>: integer type
>  0    unconditional
>  1    mobile busy
>  2    no reply
>  3    not reachable
>  4    all call forwarding (refer 3GPP TS 22.030 [19])
>  5    all conditional call forwarding (refer 3GPP TS 22.030 [19])
>  <mode>: integer type
>  0    disable
>  1    enable
>  2    query status
>  3    registration
>  4    erasure
> ```

So you need to issue the command accordingly

For example, to check the status of call forwarding when busy:

- `AT+CCFC=1,2` : Check status of call forwarding when busy
- `AT+CCFC=1,4` : Remove call forward when busy number
- `AT+CCFC=2,2` : Check status of call forward when no answer

A typical reply might look like:

`+CCFC: 1,1,"+61418707111",145,,,`

From the spec;

> +CCFC: <status>,<class1>[,<number>,<type>[,<subaddr>,<satype>[,<time>]]]

So this response means that the status is enabled, for voice mode, forwards to +61418707111, with a type of address of 145

Comment: And in addition to 27.007, by all means read all of chapter 5 in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). That will teach all the necessary basics of AT command handling.

Comment: @hlovdal great resource